# how can I create a flow in power automate that allows users to acknowledge that they have read a document

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, power-automate, power-platform, microsoft365

I have created a flow that allows users to acknowledge when they read a company policy in SharePoint but I want to be able to save the name of the users that have read these policies and the name of the policy they read and store this in a SharePoint list.

So far I am able to store the names of users that acknowledge they have read and agreed to the policies  but all I can see is their names and not the policies they read in the list.

This is what I've tried so far

[image: snapshot of my current solution]

[image: snapshot of my current solution (contd.)]

Comment: How are you achieving it at the minute? Can you provide some screenshots?

Comment: sure I have attached the snapshots

Comment: What about an approval per document per user?

Comment: did you have a look at this article? https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/healthcare-and-life-sciences/document-acknowledgement-and-attestation-with-microsoft-s/ba-p/891407 May be an acceptable solution for you?
Regards